# Recommendations for C/C++ remote message queues

Tags: c++, c, linux, unix, message-queue

I am working on a project which involves several C++ programs that each take input and generate output. The data (tens to hundreds of bytes, probably JSON) essentially flows (asynchronously) in one direction, and the programs will need to be located on different Linux computers around the LAN.

Since the data flows in only one direction, I don't believe I need a transactional model like HTTP. I think a message queue model (fire and forget) makes the most sense and should simplify the logic of each program. It is probably sufficient to merely note that the message was added to the remote queue successfully.

What I am looking for are recommendations for how to implement this message queue in C or C++. It seems like [POSIX](http://linux.die.net/man/7/mq_overview) and [Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/doc/html/boost/interprocess/message_queue.html) message queues are limited to a single host, and [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/) seems to have weak C/C++ support, and [MQ4CPP](http://www.sixtyfourbit.org/mq4cpp.htm) seems inadequately supported for a business-critical role. Am I wrong about this? What about Boost [ASIO](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html) or [ACE](http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/ACE.html) or writing socket code myself? I look forward to your suggestions.

Comment: [ZeroMQ is pretty nice](http://www.zeromq.org).

Comment: Great answers, everyone, but I really like the simplicity of ZeroMQ. If @sixlettervariables were to make it an answer, I would accept it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In terms of simple messaging support, [ZeroMQ is hard to beat](http://www.zeromq.org/). It's available in many language bindings and supports everything from simple send and receive to pub/sub, fanout, or even a messaging pipeline. The code is also easy to digest and makes it pretty easy to switch between patterns.

Looking at their [Weather Update Server sample](http://zguide.zeromq.org/cpp:wuserver) (in 20 some odd languages) shows how easy it can be to create publish/subscribe setups:

```
zmq::context_t context (1);
zmq::socket_t publisher (context, ZMQ_PUB);
publisher.bind("tcp://*:5556");
publisher.bind("ipc://weather.ipc");

while(1) {
    //  Send message to all subscribers
    zmq::message_t message(20);
    snprintf ((char *) message.data(), 20 ,
        "%05d %d %d", zipcode, temperature, relhumidity);
    publisher.send(message);
}
```

I've used it on some mixed C# and Python processes without much hassle.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, if I understand the question, I think that you should use a lower-level TCP connection. It has all of the guarantied delivery that you want, and has a rather good Berkley Sockets API. 
I've found that if your willing to implement a very simple protocol (eg. four-byte NBO message length, *n* bytes of data), you can get very simple, very customizable, and very simple. If you go with this, you also (as mentioned) get great C support (which means C++ support, although things aren't in classes and methods). The socket code is also very easy, and they have asynchronous IO with the standard async flags for the Linux/UNIX/POSIX IO functions (thats one of the other benefits, if you know anything about POSIX programing, you basically know the socket API).

One of the best resources for learning the socket API are:

- Beej's Guide to Network Programing: http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/, this is very good if you need the overall programming model in addition to specifics
- Man Pages: If you just need function signatures, return values, and arguments, these are all you need. I find the Linux ones to be very well written and useful (Proof: Look at my console: `man`, `man`, `man`, `man`, `man`, `make`, `man`, ...)

Also, for making data network-sendable, if your data is JSON, you have no worries. Because JSON is just ASCII (or UTF-8), it can be sent raw over the network with only a length header. Unless your trying to send something complicated in binary, this should be perfect (if you need complicated in binary, either look at serialization or prepare for a lot of `Segmentation Fault`).

---

Also, you probably, if you go the socket path, want to use TCP. Although UDP will give you the one-way aspect, the fact that making it reliable is pitting your home-baked solution against the top-of-the-line TCP given by the Linux kernel, TCP is an obvious option.

Answer (score 2):

RabbitMQ is just one implementation of [AMQP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AMQP).  You might want to investigate [Apache Qpid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Qpid) or other variants that might be more C/C++ friendly.  There is a [libamqp](https://github.com/libamqp/libamqp) for C though I have no first hand experience with it.  I don't know exactly what your requirements are but AMQP, properly implemented, is industrial strength and should be orders of magnitude faster and more stable than anything you are going to build by hand in a short amount of time.

Answer (score 1):

I am using Boost Serialization and socket sending for a similar application. You can find an example of serialization here :

http://code.google.com/p/cloudobserver/wiki/TutoriaslBoostSerialization

And on this page:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples.html

under serialization you will find examples on how to make servers and clients. Make one server on a particular port and you can generate multiple clients on multiple computers which can communicate with that port.

The downside to using boost serialization is that it has a large overhead if you have a simple data structure to be serialized but it does make it easy.

Answer (score 1):

Another recommendation is the distributed framework [OpenCL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCL). The document [The OpenCL C++ Wrapper for API](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/specs/opencl-cplusplus-1.1.pdf) provides further information on the library. In particular, the API function `cl::CommandQueue` could be of interest for creating queues on devices within a network setup.

Answer (score 1):

Another messaging solution is ICE (http://www.zeroc.com/). It is multi-platform, multi-language. It uses more of an RPC approach.

Comment: While it is a great product, [ICE is GPLed](http://www.zeroc.com/licensing.html).  Unless your code is GPLed as well or are willing to pay for a commercial license, I'd steer clear of it.